# Tail-Recursive Function (Coursera Issues)

Tags: scala, syntax, tail-recursion, higher-order-functions

I'm following a Coursera course for functional programming in Scala so that I can learn the language.

They introduced the concept of tail-recursive functions and defined them basically as a function that ends in a call to itself.  But then they show this as the worked example:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  def loop(a: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (a > b) acc
    else loop(a + 1, f(a) + acc)
  }
  loop(a, 0)
}
```

If I annotate sum with @tailrec, I get an error because the IDE (IntelliJ) does not consider it to be tail recursive.

Is sum called tail-recursive here, or is the inner implementation "loop" the thing that is considered to be tail recursive in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. `sum` needs to call itself otherwise Scala will complain with:

```
@tailrec annotated method contains no recursive calls
```

If you tell compiler where exactly it is, by moving the `@tailrec` to where the tail recursion is:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec def loop(a: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (a > b) acc
    else loop(a + 1, f(a) + acc)
  }
  loop(a, 0)
}
```

Then the compiler'll be satisfied it is tail-recursion optimised.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `loop` method is tail-recursive, the `sum` method is not recursive at all. Therefore, you should annotate `loop` with `@tailrec`.

Moving `loop` to the outer scope may help visualize what's going on:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    loop(a, 0)
}

def loop(a: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (a > b) acc
    else loop(a + 1, f(a) + acc)
}
```

As you can see, `sum` is merely a public entry point for `loop`.

(Note that the code above won't compile because `loop` does not close over `b` or `f` anymore, but you get the point.)